# Using ESS in console Emacs

Tags: comint, process, ess

When I start Emacs 24.4.1 for Windows with the `-nw` option, I am unable to start R via <kbd>Meta</kbd>+`R`.  Emacs becomes unrensponsive and I have to kill the process.

The problem seems connected with the call in `(R)`:

```
(inferior-ess r-start-args cust-alist gdbp)
```

By debugging I see `r-start-args` is set to "--no-readline", but I am not able to debug `inferior-ess`. In fact  Edebug gives: `Debugger entered: nil`, without stepping through code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Source of the problem

So the problem  is in the ESS variable `ess-microsoft-p`. Defined as:

```
(defvar ess-microsoft-p (or (equal window-system 'w32)
                            (equal window-system 'win32)
                            (equal window-system 'mswindows))
  "Value is t if the OS is one of Microsoft's, nil otherwise.")
```

When you run Emacs from a Windows console, `window-system` is `nil` (because a character terminal is not at all a window system),  therefore such is `ess-microsoft-p`. Eventually the predicate says that you are not running on a Microsoft OS!

The unpleasant now follows, in fact, as for  <kbd>Meta</kbd>-`R`, we have:

```
(defun R (&optional start-args)
  "Call 'R', the 'GNU S' system from the R Foundation. .....
If you have certain command line arguments that should always be passed
to R, put them in the variable `inferior-R-args'."
...
  (let* ((r-always-arg
          (if (or ess-microsoft-p (eq system-type 'cygwin))
              "--ess "
            ;; else: "unix alike"
            (if (not ess-R-readline) "--no-readline ")))
         (r-start-args
          (concat r-always-arg
                  inferior-R-args " " ; add space just in case
...
  (inferior-ess r-start-args cust-alist gdbp)
...
```

As you can see if  `ess-microsoft-p` is false and the `system-type` is not Cygwin, the function `(R)` assumes we are running Linux, therefore sets `r-always-arg` to `--no-readline` instead of  `-ess`. This variable is appended to `r-always-arg` and passed to the command line invoking R thorough `(inferior-ess)`.

`--no-readline` is a Unix only argument to invoke R,  turning  off command-line editing via readline. R will not start with this switch in Windows and Emacs will hang, infinitely waiting for R.

It should be noted that if you run a native Windows Emacs in a Cygwin console you incur in the same problem, since  `(eq system-type 'cygwin)` is true when Emacs is *compiled for* Cygwin, not when *running in* Cygwin.

### Solution

To me the current definition of `ess-microsoft-p` seems buggy.
Anyway you can fix it, adding in your init file, after starting ESS. i.e. `(require 'ess-site)`:

```
(setq ess-microsoft-p t)
```

### UPDATE

Now `ess-microsoft-p` is:

```
(defvar ess-microsoft-p (or (eq system-type 'ms-dos)
                (eq system-type 'windows-nt))
  "Value is t if the OS is one of Microsoft's, nil otherwise.")
```

`system-type` is independent from the windowing system, therefore  `ess-microsoft-p`  correctly reports `t` in Windows console too.